# How to add text to each image using ImageGrid?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
import numpy as np

im = np.arange(100)
im.shape = 10, 10

fig = plt.figure(1, (4., 4.))
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,  
             nrows_ncols=(2, 2),  
             axes_pad=0.1,  
             )

for i in range(4):
    grid[i].imshow(im)  

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `fig.text()` to add annotations, use `axes.set_title()` to title axes.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
import numpy as np

im = np.arange(100)
im.shape = 10, 10

fig = plt.figure(1, (4., 4.))
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,
                 nrows_ncols=(2, 2),
                 axes_pad=0.4,
                 )

for axes in grid:
    axes.set_title("TITLE", fontdict=None, loc='center', color = "k")
    axes.imshow(im)


fig.text(0.7,0.2,"Anotation", color ="k")
fig.text(0.2,0.7,"Anotation", color ="k")


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!